# How to compute integral of partial derivative in R?

Tags: r, integral

First time trying out the `Deriv` package. I was trying to compute a very simple integral of partial derivative as a start:

[image]

Here's my attempt:

```
junk <- function (m) {
  -m*eval(deriv(~((exp(0.1*(100-94.5)^2))/(exp(0.1*(100-94.5)^2)+exp(0.1* 
(m-95)^2)+exp(0.1*(m-96)^2))),"m"))
}
integrate(junk, lower = 100, upper = 100.5)
```

which gives me a wrong answer of -24.30757, rather than 12.383. Can anyone shed some light on how to fix this please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is, that `deriv()` does not return an expression. For uni variate derivation use `D()`

```
junk <- function (m) {
  -m*eval(D(expression((exp(0.1*(100-94.5)^2))/(exp(0.1*(100-94.5)^2)+exp(0.1*(m-95)^2)+exp(0.1*(m-96)^2))),"m")
}
integrate(junk, lower = 100, upper = 100.5)
```

> 12.38271 with absolute error < 1.4e-13

For comparison:

return of `deriv()` - call

```
deriv(expression((exp(0.1*(100-94.5)^2))/(exp(0.1*(100-94.5)^2)+exp(0.1* 
                                                                        (m-95)^2)+exp(0.1*(m-96)^2))),"m"))
```

> ```
>  expression({
>      .expr4 <- exp(0.1 * (100 - 94.5)^2)
>      .expr5 <- m - 95
>      .expr8 <- exp(0.1 * .expr5^2)
>      .expr10 <- m - 96
>      .expr13 <- exp(0.1 * .expr10^2)
>      .expr14 <- .expr4 + .expr8 + .expr13
>      .value <- .expr4/.expr14
>      .grad <- array(0, c(length(.value), 1L), list(NULL, c("m")))
>      .grad[, "m"] <- -(.expr4 * (.expr8 * (0.1 * (2 * .expr5)) + 
>          .expr13 * (0.1 * (2 * .expr10)))/.expr14^2)
>      attr(.value, "gradient") <- .grad
>      .value })
> ```

return of `D()` -  expression

```
D(expression((exp(0.1*(100-94.5)^2))/(exp(0.1*(100-94.5)^2)+exp(0.1*(m-95)^2)+exp(0.1*(m-96)^2))),"m")
```

> ```
>  -((exp(0.1 * (100 - 94.5)^2)) * (exp(0.1 * (m - 95)^2) * (0.1 * 
>      (2 * (m - 95))) + exp(0.1 * (m - 96)^2) * (0.1 * (2 * (m - 
>      96))))/(exp(0.1 * (100 - 94.5)^2) + exp(0.1 * (m - 95)^2) + 
>      exp(0.1 * (m - 96)^2))^2)
> ```

so with your syntax and the `eval()` you need another expression which is provided by `D()`. Or you use the call object, either way is possible.